# React-Native: facebook login "invalid scope:mail" issue

Tags: react-native

I have root.js and have a LoginScreen.

This is what root looks like.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
      if(user){
        //logged in!
        console.log("logged in!");
      } else {
        //logged out!
        console.log("logged out!");
      }
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <LoginScreen />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And my loginScreen is:

```
async loginWithFacebook (){
    const {type, token} = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
      "2073519281256416",
      {permissions:["mail", "public_profile"]}
    );

    if(type == "success"){
      const credentials = fire.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
      fire.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("error is ", error);
      })
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{backgroundColor: "green"}}
          onPress={()=> this.loginWithFacebook()}>
          <Text>Login with Facebook!</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

when I click the button, it sending me facebook page. But there is an error which is invalid scope: mail. Okay. When I try to put loginWithFacebook function into Root js and Button too, then there is no problem. I can connect... but why I can't connect from LoginScreen smoothly?

Comment: there is no `mail` permission. It should be `email`. For more information please check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-email)

Comment: yes, you are very right sir! :) my little typo.